# ExpressionEngine pages doesn't work besides home

Tags: php, content-management-system, expressionengine

My ExpressionEngine database got deleted,after contacting my web hoosting provider they recovered the database. However the name of database was changed.
So i did go to ftp and change database information inside config file. Website went up and looked like it worked, hovewer when i clicked on some of the pages in the menu i get sended to 404 page.

Here is the list what i have tried.
1. Clear cache 
2. Doing all the things from EE's documentation ["Moving ExpressionEngine to Another Server"](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html)
3. Link to some other pages in menu

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer so the problem is solved by adding one simple code to .htacces.

Here it is, hope it helps someone:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```